# How to find out changes from the created date branch to current time

Tags: cvs

I created a branch name **ABC123** in my cvs repository, but i forgot to tag it.
So now i want to find out changes from the created branch date to current time.

I've tried: **cvs diff -D20090619 source**
but it is not successful.

CVS is quite bad than SVN in this kind of comparison.

Could anyone shed me any light on this?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Minh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. 
I just checkout code before that day and compare with current one.
**cvs update -r BRANCH_NAME -D20090619** (tree1)
**cvs update -r BRANCH_NAME** (tree2)

Then use Araxis Merge to compare 2 folders.